# How to use regex to split by last occurrence of underscore

Tags: regex

I want to split lines by last occurrence of underscore like this :

**Input :**

```
MANY_TIME_T1=PANORAMA17
MANY_TIME_T2=OK STATUS
MANY_TIME_T1=PANORAMA18
MANY_TIME_T2=OK STATUS
COMMENT=OK
LAST<LIGNE1
```

**Output :**

```
Match 1 : MANY_TIME_T1=PANORAMA17
Group 1 : MANY_TIME
Group 2 : T1
Group 3 : =
Group 4 : PANORAMA17

Match 2 : MANY_TIME_T2=OK STATUS
Group 1 : MANY_TIME
Group 2 : T2
Group 3 : =
Group 4 : OK STATUS

Match 3 : MANY_TIME_T1=PANORAMA18
Group 1 : MANY_TIME
Group 2 : T1
Group 3 : =
Group 4 : PANORAMA18

Match 4 : MANY_TIME_T2=OK STATUS
Group 1 : MANY_TIME
Group 2 : T2
Group 3 : =
Group 4 : OK STATUS

Match 5 : COMMENT=OK
Group 1 : COMMENT
Group 3 : =
Group 4 : OK

Match 6 : LAST<LIGNE1
Group 1 : LAST
Group 3 : <
Group 4 : LIGNE1
```

I try this regex `^\s*([^_<>=]+)(_\w+)?([<>=%])(.*)$` to split by underscore but it can't split by last occurence like as above.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BCC5o/1)

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: So if suddenly your input is `something_important` you want the *"wrong"* output `something` and `important` separated, right?

Comment: Also please explain the output for `LAST<LIGNE1`, it seems that the `<` becomes an `=` in the output, which isn't possible with pure regex.

Comment: I just put an expected result like the website : regex101. i don't need to use a specific language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\s*(\w+?)(?:_([^\W_]+))?([<>=%])(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM8m6L/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+?)` - Group 1: one or more word chars, as few as possible
- `(?:_([^\W_]+))?` - an optional occurrence of `_` and the one or more word chars except underscore captured into Group 2
- `([<>=%])` - Group 3: one of the specified chars
- `(.*)` - Group 4: the rest of the line.